# Webpack "cannot find module" source-map, module build failed

Tags: typescript, webpack, css-loader, extract-text-plugin

I'm trying to bundle project with Webpack, but I recieve an error: "Cannot find module './stylesheet/css/build.css'"
I'm using webpack 1.14.0 and yarn 0.17.10. 
[webpack printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZSyC.png)

Please give me some advise how I should use require() to get result.

Thanks in advise for your help!

### webpack.dev.js

```
  var config = {
      cache: true,
      devtool: 'source-map',
      entry: {
        polyfills: './src/polyfills',
        vendor:    './src/vendor',
        main:      './src/main'
      },

      output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
      },

      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.ts$/,   loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' },
          { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
          { test: /\.html/,  loader: 'raw-loader' },
          { test: /\.css$/,  loader: 'to-string-loader!css-loader' },
          { test: /\.css$/,  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?minimize')}
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
          new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: ['polyfills', 'vendor', 'main'].reverse(), minChunks: Infinity }),
          new ExtractTextPlugin('/src/stylesheet/css/zio.css')
      ],

      resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src']
      }
    };
```

### main.ts

```
require("./stylesheet/css/build.css");

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    App,
    Main,
    Auth,
    AppHeader
  ],
  providers,
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    routes
  ],
  bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Additional information -  [structure of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRPRw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the [`ExtractTextPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/blob/webpack-1/README.md) as such:

```
// webpack.config.js

var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader") }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ]
}
```

Then you can require the CSS sheets as you have done already:

```
require("./stylesheet/css/build.css");
require("./src/stylesheet/css/zio.css");
// and so on ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dotcs, but I just recieved another error: 

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./src/stylesheet/css/build.css in /home/andrii/WebstormProjects/pallybet_frontend_bvb/src
 @ ./src/main.ts 20:0-41

I'm writting require ("./stylesheet/css/build.css") in typescript file main.ts (entry point), maybe I need to write it another place? 

Thanks!

Comment: This means that webpack cannot resolve the file path you have given. Can you add information about your file structure to the question? The path should be relative to the `main.ts` file. So if `main.ts` lives in the `src` folder and the stylesheet is located at `src/stylesheet/css/build.css` the path should be `require('./stylesheet/css/build.css')`.

Comment: I've added structure of project.

I understand your answer and I can understand how it should wotk but,
after I used require('./stylesheet/css/build.css'), I still have an error: 
"ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./src/stylesheet/css/build.css
Module build failed: Unknown word (5:1)"

If you have more advises it would be pleasure for me to get them and solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: You should not require the css file in the `webpack.dev.js` file, but for example in the `main.ts`. The reason is that `webpack.dev.js` describes the webpack pipeline, whereas `main.ts` is included and transformed by the pipeline. In case you have done this already it would be nice to see the `build.css`, because from the error 'Unknown word' I'd say that there is something in the file that should not be there.